# SQL Table Relationships

Tags: sql

I am attempting to create some table relationships for a SQL database  that handles service activity on a work order ticket. I have one-to-may relationships for these tables and have a question.
I have WOT (Work Order Ticket) table for the creation of a work order ticket.
The WOT can have multiple service activities on different dates associated with it.
Each service activity can have multiple parts used (for a repair).
This is just the basic idea, but I have created the following tables and relationships:

```
WOT Table:
```

> wot>wotnum – PK

```
Service Activity Table:
```

> service_activity>serviceid – PK
>
> service_activity>wotnum – FK   (link to PK in WOT table)

```
Part Used Table:
```

> partused>partusedid – PK
>
> partused>serviceid – FK (link to PK in Service Activity table)

Each of the tables above has other columns as well (not shown), but they are unique to the table, such as date fields, part numbers, etc.

The `service_activity>serviceid (PK)` field is an autoincrement field and so is the `partused>partusedid (PK)` field as well.

My question is, during data entry, how do I insure the partused>serviceid field (FK) synced with the `service_activity>serviceid field (PK)` without actually having to manually enter the `partused>serviceid field (FK)`?

Although I have a decent understanding of tables and relationships (critical to get this correct now), I am a bit of a neophyte as to the process of thinking through how the tables will interact during actual data input. I think the answer to this may be simple, but I am just not grasping it yet. If my current solution does not seem adequate, I would welcome a suggestion. I need some help to get going in the right direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "without actually having to manually enter the partused>serviceid field"?   What other way do you think the field might be entered if not manually?   I'm not even sure what you mean by "manually" in this context.

Comment: I think he needed to understand better how a FK works :p

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the FK correctly, when you manually enter the `partused.serviceid` column data during data entry, it will automatically refer the `service_activity.serviceid` column.

For example: If you have only one service_activity with `serviceid = 456`.

1. When you attempt insert data in the table partused with `partused.serviceid = 500`, it will throw an error and the insertion will not be allowed.
2. When you attempt to insert data in the table partused with `partused.serviceid = 456`, it will be successful as the referenced row in the other table indeed exists.

Comment: Thanks! I think that answered my question. I am going to go with this table structure and see what happens.

Comment: @gitpicker Okay! If you think it answered your question, please accept my answer :)